# How to send an application to the background?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

I wrote a hello world application. I want it so when the close button is pressed, the application remains running in the background. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This discussion](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/183023-run-application-background.html) might help you. (If you are programming for blackberry):

> To put an application in the
>   background call
>   Application.requestBackground(),
>   possibly as mentioned in the onClose()
>   method.

Comment: It's helpful to summarize the relevant part of a link here